# Replace Nginx "No input file specified message" with blank or another?

Tags: php, nginx

Is possible to replace message "No input file specified." with another message or blank in Nginx? I want to visitor of my website not show anything if my server get error like that.

My server use Nginx, PHP-FPM, MySQL.

Comment: The message is from a backend (php) so you need to catch this with nginx before it goes to the backend with something like try_files.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to appear with 404 HTTP error code so just override 404:

```
location / {
    error_page    404 = /404.html;
}
```

Make sure you have styled 404.html before update the configuration.